# How do I access footnotes using office-js?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am implementing an Office-Addin and need to access the footnotes (from references). How do I do that?

I have looked through the reference docs and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Footnote API. You have to use OOXML and insert footnotes into the document.

It could be considered a workaround, but I wouldn't call it one because of how incredibly buggy and crash-prone the OOXML Footnotes piece is (as in, it crashes Word).

I've had a ticket open for 1.5 years and there hasn't been any progress:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/106

Wish I had better news for you.

Here you can see the gist of what I put in the Github ticket and how I added footnotes using OOXML. https://gist.github.com/sureshjoshi/4566f04da8d5431ddbe0e23cffce2185